# Why can't I eager load a nested association from my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, eager-loading

I'm trying to eager load a nested association. I've read through the [Rails Guide (13.1.2)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) and a couple of blog posts on the subject, but I'm still struggling to grasp why the following code operates the way that it does.

It seems to me that `includes` should be doing exactly what I need here, but when I run my code, it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. I've also tried `preload` and `eager_load` with identical results.

Models:

```
class Product
  has_many assets
end

class Post
  has_many products
end
```

Controller:

```
@post_products = @post.products.includes(:assets)
```

Console:

```
@post_products.first.assets.first == nil
//=> true
```

Comment: What happens if you just do `Post.find(<some_existing_id>).products.map(&:assets)`?

Comment: The code you run in a console does not prove anything - it only shows that the first product has no assets and will return nil regardless of whether you eager-loaded the association.

Comment: @BroiSatse I've confirmed that this product does have assets. If I do `Product.find_by(the_same_id).assets.first` I get my asset. It's only when I try to load it through the post that I can't access my assets.

Comment: @CDub It returns  `[#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>]`, but I'm not entirely sure what this is. I'm very new to Rails and Ruby. What should I be expecting from that code?

Comment: Eh, this is one of this cases when we should go straight to the chat room, the code you posted cannot behave the way you described unless there is something else you didn't tell us. How do you define @post_products in the console?

Comment: I will happily meet you in chat. I'm actually running the console from BetterErrors which is firing from inside the controller. This gives me access to everything defined in the controller. @post is the post that I'm trying to load via my browser, and I define `@post_products = @post.products`. I can reproduce all of this from a standard console, though.

Comment: So, it's returning an empty array.  Thus there are no assets for any product on the given `Post`...  Your code seems right - it's a lack of data.

Comment: @CDub Here's the kicker, though `Product.find_by(@post.product.first.id).assets.first` is NOT `nil`. That product HAS assets. It's just that the view/console doesn't load that association unless you specifically run a `Product.find`.